# In-App Browser - if the page is not loading - Display message

Tags: android, ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I am very new to `Cordova`. I am doing an application in `Cordova` platform , in that I am opening a link using `InAppbrowser`. I am trying to do a  a approach like If the mobile phone `INTERNET` speed is slow . Then IN-app Browser page load is taking long time and its keep spinning for longer duration. 
  In-App Browser - if the page is not loading – I want to  show some message like “server error image” . Can anyone please help me to resolve this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think InAppBrowser has an option for this. But you can check for internet connection before opening the link. If there is no internet connection you can show a message to the user, like: "No Internet connection! Please check your connection and try again!"

```
if (navigator && navigator.onLine === false){
//show your warning message
}else{
//open your link using inappbrowser
}
```

Comment: Can't we do timeout of the process in InAppbrowser?

Comment: Check the documentation of InAppBrowser